# Fourier transform of a pseudo-differential operator.

Tags: operator-theory

In general, if $A$ is a pseudo-differential operator defined over Schwartz space functions (by example) with $(Au)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathrm{e}^{ix\cdot \xi}a(x,\xi)\widehat{u}(\xi)\,d\xi$ where $a(x,\xi)$ is the symbol of $A$. Is it possible to say something about $\widehat{Au}(x)$ (at least formally
)?

Playing I only get this:
\begin{align}
\widehat{Au}(x)&=\int \mathrm{e}^{-ix\cdot \xi}Au(\xi)\,d\xi\\
&=\int \mathrm{e}^{-ix\cdot \xi} \int\mathrm{e}^{i\xi\cdot y}a(\xi,y)\widehat{u}(y)\,dy\,d\xi\\
&=\int\int\mathrm{e}^{-i\xi\cdot (x-y)}a(\xi,y)\widehat{u}(y)\,dy\,d\xi
\end{align}

Comment: Is this not $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{a}(x-y,y)\,\widehat{u}(y)\,dy$?

Comment: Certain. And now that I see, it seems that it is trying to form a convolution if it were not for the $x-y$ in $p(x-y,y)$

Comment: My knowledge about pseudo-differential operators is very rusty and I have given away the only book on them I ever owned. When the symbol does not depend on $y$ I think the operator has "constant coefficents". Then we have a convolution.

Comment: If $a(x,\xi)=a(\xi)$ then $Au(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}((a(\xi)\widehat{u}(\xi))(x)$. Then $\widehat{Au}(x)=a(x)\widehat{u}(x)$ but with variable coefficients it gets complicated

Comment: What do you want to say about it?